# How to use Cloud Firestore in a non-realtime fashion?

Tags: angularfire2, google-cloud-firestore

I've really been investing a lot of time integrating Firestore into my new apps and I'm loving it so far. One thing I noticed is it's very much "realtime" as it touts. This is awesome for writing chat apps, etc, but for non "realtime" features of those apps, it seems kind of excessive to use the Observable pattern for that as you're really probably only attempting to grab a list (not an add, update or delete event) or even a single item and doing the map on a snapshotChange gets a little repetitive in this case as well.

Is there a suggested or recommended way to use Firestore in an almost "RESTful" manner? I'm using the AngularFire2 library if that matters at all. Is it just suggested to use the firestore methods from the firebase npm packages?

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be confusing Firebase Realtime Database and Firebase Firestore.

Firebase Realtime Database is very much as you describe in that it is expected you will subscribe to a stream of updates for the data you are interested in. Functionality is provided for "one-time" reads but the product name, documentation and samples often portray real-time scenarios.

Cloud Firestore, on the other hand, does not make these assumptions but still provides the option of real-time stream updates or "one-time" reads.

For deciding between the 2, you should read [Google's own document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/rtdb-vs-firestore) on what they believe the suitability of each is.

If you decide to use Firestore, a sample "one-time" read is [documented here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart#read_data).

Comment: Hey Tom, thanks for the answer. I definitely understand the differences between the two, and understand they're both more or less realtime. I guess my question might actually have been more of an angularfire2 reference... It seems like if I want the "one-time" read I should be using the firestore methods from the firebase npm package instead of the AF2 methods that return observables.